# PHP Fatal error: Ca ll to undefined function json_encode() ..?

Tags: php, freebsd, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable json_decode() on my system](https://serverfault.com/questions/114283/enable-json-decode-on-my-system)

Im trying to use json with php and i keep getting the error `"PHP Fatal error:  Ca
ll to undefined function json_encode()"`. I am using php version 5.3.6 and on phpinfo(); nothing mentions json. Any suggestions? (using freeBSD)

Comment: check ini to see if the extension json.so is commented

Answer (score 0):

Install `pear-Services_JSON` with:

```
pkg_add -r pear-Services_JSON
```